# Lightswitch: Load operation failed for query 'GetAuthenticationInfo'. The remote server returned an error: NotFound

Tags: silverlight, iis, service, web, visual-studio-lightswitch

I'm currently creating a small silverlight application for testing, to see if it can works with other projects.

In debug, everything is working, but once I deploy it to my local IIS Server, I got this error:

> Load operation failed for query 'GetAuthenticationInfo'. The remote
>   server returned an error: NotFound.

I've done a lot of research on the net, but nothing seems to resolve my problem.

- I've the anonymous mode correctly enabled(and all other not) I've
- done a clean publish on my IIS(7.5) from visual studio
- My IIS has the two IIS lightswitch extensions, installed through the WPI
- I'm not using the beta version

The application is just displaying some list, I've the windows auth set.

I've tried to publish as a Desktop application, as a Web application for the Client configuration, and Application serverconfiguration set to local or IIS Server, it's always the same problem(the goal is to have a two tier application(database - application), but hosted in an htm file).

I can't find what is going wrong, My IIS is just fresh installed with all components

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try restoring .NET Framework 4 at first, before diving into the problem deeper.

This solved the problem in my case

Answer (score 2):

check that if you ".net framework 4.5 advanced service->WCF service -> HTTP activation" is checked or not , I solved it by this way.

Comment: you are a life saver :))

Answer (score 0):

When I get that darn "Not Found" ( which could be any number of things ) I crank up [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/version.asp) and examine what is actually being returned by the web service.  If you do that, you'll see the real error and a lot more about what's happening in the communications.

Comment: does fiddler intercept things which doesn't leave my computer

Comment: I tried with the chrome developer console, and it seems that he send a request to http://localhost/SilverlightTest/Web/Microsoft-LightSwitch-Security-ServerGenerated-Implementation-AuthenticationService.svc/binary/GetAuthenticationInfo and receive a 404 error. Where does this service comes from?

Comment: Hmm. Not sure.  But have you seen the 3-tier deployment help files? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg481778.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I **only** had .NET Framework 4.5 installed on the server. 
My solution was:

1. Uninstall .NET Framework 4.5 (you have to do that in order to install .NET Framework 4.0)
2. Install .NET Framework 4.0
3. Reinstall .NET Framework 4.5

Make sure that you site runs under the applicationpool ASP.NET v4.0.